# Cascade persist JPA entities with unknown PK/FK attributes violates NotNullConstraint

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I would like to persist a JPA entity with many 1:1 or 1:many relationships with only one call to `persist`.

**Problem:** the entity's primary key is auto generated and used as a foreign key in a child entity. When the transaction is committed, there is an exception pointing out a violated NotNullConstraint on the child entity's foreign key column.

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01400: Insertion of
>   NULL in ("SCHEMA"."PROTOCOL_FILE"."PROTOCOL_ID") not possible

Parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "...")
public class Protocol {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="SQ_PROTOCOL", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SQ_PROTOCOL", sequenceName="SQ_PROTOCOL", allocationSize=50)
    @Column(name = "PROTOCOL_ID")
    private Long protocolId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="protocol", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ProtocolFile file;

    //Other attributes and getter/setter omitted
}
```

Child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROTOCOL_FILE")
public class ProtocolFile {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROTOCOL_ID")
    private Long protocolId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumns(@JoinColumn(name="PROTOCOL_ID", referencedColumnName="PROTOCOL_ID", updatable=false, insertable=false))
    private Protocol protocol;

    //Other attributes and getter/setter omitted
}
```

Do you know a convenient solution, so I can persist all entities, that belong to `Protocol`, in one call?

Comment: Why did you use @JoinColumns? Have you tried without it?

Comment: @David_Ware When I remove @JoinColumns, then the insert statement looks like `INSERT INTO PROTOCOL_FILE(PROTOCOL_ID, ....., PROTOCOL_PROTOCOL_ID) VALUES (?, ...... , ?)
 bind => [null, ........ , 3351]`. As you can see, the insert statement uses a proper ID, but it's addressing a non-existing table column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you have here is a "derived identity" of the `ProtocolFile` - the ID of the `ProtocolFile` is the ID of the `Protocol` and there is a one-to-one relationship between them.

I see you are using `updatable=false, insertable=false` but it's better to follow the specs which suggest to use the `@MapsId` annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROTOCOL_FILE")
public class ProtocolFile {

    @Id // No @Column here
    private Long protocolId;

    @MapsId // --- HERE
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="PROTOCOL_ID") // Just that
    private Protocol protocol;
}
```

Or you may want to skip the `protocolId` field altogether and put the `@Id` annotation on the relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROTOCOL_FILE")
public class ProtocolFile {

    @Id // --- HERE
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="PROTOCOL_ID") // Just that
    private Protocol protocol;
}
```

Of course, you need to set the `protocol` instance to the `file` during creation and not change it later any more (eg. allow to set it only using the `ProtocolFile` constructor).

See section "2.4.1 Primary Keys Corresponding to Derived Identities" of the [JPA 2.0 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) for more details and examples (*Example 4* seems to be your case).

Comment: Thanks alot. This seems to identify and fix the problem.