# JPA: How to implement a composite primary key with derived IdClass?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am implementing the following table structure with JPA entities, where the shown attributes represent PK/FK columns. The protocolId is auto-generated and set as null in all entities before the call to `persist()`. The entire structure is stored at once.

[image: Table relationships]

With the [help of a stackoverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627062/cascade-persist-jpa-entities-with-unknown-pk-fk-attributes-violates-notnullconst) and [JPA spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/), I resolved the derived identity in `Position`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="...")
@IdClass(PositionID.class)
public class Position {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "POSITION_ID")
    private int positionId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(...)
    @JoinColumn(name="PROTOCOL_ID")
    private Protocol protocol;    


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="position")
    private Collection<Item>
}


public class PositionID implements Serializable{
    private int protocol;
    private int positionId;
}
```

The above relationship works, but I have trouble implementing the derived identity in `Item`. 
This is the version, that I wrote according to the specification in chapter *2.4.1.3 Examples of Derived Identities*:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="...")
@IdClass(ItemId.class)
public class Item {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ITEM_NAME")
    private String itemName;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(...)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="POSITION_ID", referencedColumnName="POSITION_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name="PROTOCOL_ID", referencedColumnName="PROTOCOL_ID")
    })
    private Position position;
}

public class ItemId implements Serializable {
    private String itemName;
    private PositionId position;
}
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following error:

> Invalid composite primary key specification. The names of the primary
>   key fields or properties in the primary key class [null] and those of
>   the entity bean class [class ......Item] must
>   correspond and their types must be the same.

How can I implement the identity for `Item`?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with this model, and it appears to mirror the model EclipseLink tests against.  What version are you using, and can you show the full stack trace?  It is odd that it shows as null in the primary key class.

Comment: @Chris I copied the text to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=hMd00wXc)

Comment: This stack is incomplete, as it only has the stack for the PersistenceUnitLoadingException, not the internal ValidationException that we are looking into.

Comment: it also shows you are using EclipseLink 2.3.2 - any chance you might try 2.5 or 2.6?

Comment: Something does not smell right in the error message. The message is missing the Id class name (in this case, `ItemId`); as it says "...the primary key class [null]...". Seems like it should say "...the primary key class [class ...ItemId]...". Maybe that is a hint as to what is wrong? Or the error message is improperly generated by EclipseLink. : )

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a combined primary key!

In your main entity (Item) you use this:

```
@EmbeddedId
private CombinedPK id;
```

And in the CombinedPK you set this:

```
@Embeddable // Annotation on class level
public class CombinedPK {
    ...
    @Column(name = "positionId")
    private Integer positionId;

    @Column(name = "protocolId")
    private Integer protocolId;
}
```

The columns in the CombinedPK can then be mapped as you normally would, each for itself.

Additionally, remove the `@Id` annotation from your `position` field and add `insertable=false, updatable=false` to your `@JoinColumn` annotations.

The problem is that in your Java model you have (and need) two different representations of the same data from SQL: you need the primary key to be modeled and annotated, and you also need the foreign key relationship.  JPA does not handle this very well, and JPA also forbids changing the primary key of a record. If you can change the database you will find it easier to add a ['SERIAL'](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html) column to your item table and use it as the primary key (and add a composite unique constraint on the foreign key columns).

Comment: I tested the `@EmbeddedId`, but I seem to miss something: after the call to `persist()`, but before committing the transaction, the IDs for `Protocol` and `Position` are set. Yet, the embedded Id in `Item` is still null and I receive a message `Missing mapping for field [POSITION.protocolId].` upon `commit()`

Comment: You might have to set those IDs "manually", depending on your use case! Or is there a reason why the JPA engine might know those IDs? I mean, the point in time where you create a new Item, you probably have references to those other two entities, right? Use them to set the foreign keys!

Comment: you would use MapsId on your relationship mapping if you are going to remap the join columns in an EmbeddedId, to allow the provider to know that the ID values within it are to come from the relationship mapping

Comment: @cslotty No I don't know the IDs before persisting the entities. It would be very inconvenient to set the IDs for every child entity (see the linked SO question). Instead, I would like JPA to insert the auto-generated ID in all child entities.

Comment: I couldn't convince JPA (Hibernate in my case) to do that for me ;-)

Comment: @SME_Dev, how is JPA supposed to know which protocol and position you want to assign your Item to!? You have to set that relationship someplace.... and in that same place, you can take care of fetching the relevant IDs and putting them into your new Item.

Comment: @cslotty Well, the object-relationships are manually set, but I don't manually set each primary key attribute. I thought, you were suggesting the latter.

Comment: @SME_Dev, yes I was suggesting setting the IDs, too! On setting the object relationships (assuming that you do that in the Item class) you could easily add two lines to use the IDs of the parent entities - if you have them (those IDs) at that point - that's why I'm saying that you might have to persist the parent first. I couldn't find a way to avoid this! But anyways, good luck to you.